# Divide start time to end Time int 10 intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server

If you have start time : Time columns

Example   10:10:01   to   10:10:31

in need to group by 10 intervals :

Example

```
     10:10:01  to   10:10:04 ,
     10:10:04  to   10:10:07 ,
     10:10:07  to   10:10:10 ,
     10:10:10  to   10:10:13 ,
     10:10:13  to   10:10:16 ,
     10:10:16  to   10:10:19 ,
     10:10:19  to   10:10:22 ,
     10:10:22  to   10:10:25 ,
     10:10:25  to   10:10:28 ,
     10:10:28  to   10:10:31
```

using SQL Server

Comment: Are you using Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution ([SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18238)):

```
declare @from time = '10:10:01', @to time = '10:10:31'

declare @interval int = datediff(millisecond, @from, @to) / 10

select dateadd(millisecond, @interval * (i-1), @from) as [From], 
  dateadd(millisecond, @interval * i, @from) as [To]
from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) x(i)
```

How it works: It takes the difference - in milliseconds for good measure because the times may not always divide nicely - between the `@from` and `@to` times specified, and divides by 10 to get the interval. Then it uses a values-table as a poor man's loop (because I didn't feel like writing out a `UNION ALL` of ten queries) to produce each period's from and to times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution which works even if you change the number of wanted intervals:

```
create function "dbo"."splitIntervals"
(
    @starttime time
    , @endtime time
    , @intervals int
)
returns table
as
return
(
    with cte as
    (
        select 
            cast( @starttime as time ) as "starttime"
            , cast( dateadd( ms, datediff(ms, @starttime, @endtime) / @intervals, @starttime) as time ) as "endtime" 
        union all
        select 
            cast(dateadd( ms, datediff(ms, @starttime, @endtime) / @intervals, "starttime") as time ) as "starttime" 
            , cast( dateadd( ms, datediff(ms, @starttime, @endtime) / @intervals, "endtime") as time ) as "entime" 
        from cte where "starttime" < cast( @endtime as time )
    )
    select 
        * from "cte"
    where
        endtime <= @endtime
);

;select * from "dbo"."splitIntervals" ( '10:10:01.000', '10:10:31.000', 15)
```

[See SQL-Fiddle for working version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b767/1/0)